# Undefined dynamic step - Table inside a step reference for cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have the following situation here. A hypothetical .feature file has this:

```
Scenario Outline: Test
  Given bla bla bla
  When I input the <data>
  Then I should see a message

  Examples:
    | data  |
    | test1 |
    | test2 |
```

And I need to execute the "I input the " on a step reference.
So I have this:

```
Given('I already have data') do
  step %{input the <data>
    | data  |
    | test1 |
    | test2 |
  }
end
```

And its giving me the "Undefined dynamic step" error. What should I do in this case, to get it working?

Thanks a lot!